# While Converting from XML to JSON in java

Tags: java, xml, json

```
XMLSerializer xmlSerializer = new XMLSerializer(); 
        JSON json  = xmlSerializer.read( xmlString );  
        System.out.println( json.toString(2) );


Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: nu/xom/Serializer
    at src.main.parser.main(parser.java:19)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: nu.xom.Serializer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
... 1 more
```

While i am coverting from XML to Json i got this error ...?

How can i fix this one .

Thanks
Sankar

Comment: Check if the xom jar is in your classpath.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Download xom jar and add to your class path: 
http://www.findjar.com/jar/xom/xom/1.0/xom-1.0.jar.html

Comment: Thanks for your link , i downloaded the xom jar and its working fine .

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the library containing the `nu.xom.Serializer` class to your classpath.